# create collections for each collection exist in relations attribute of laravel collections

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I have a two models Product and Price.this two model have ***one-to-many relation (one(Product)  many(Price)***) and this relation work properly.

I want extract price attribute from product collection and create array of products collection for each price exist inside that product collection and each product collection has only one price attribute.

**when I want make new collections of products each product has last price exist in array of price collections**

```
    $products = Product::find("bf88c08cc82b1afc801db2c184266c7b");
    $products->load("price");

    $newPrices=collect();
    $newProducts = collect();

    $products->price->map(function($price) use ($newPrices) {

            $newPrices->push($price); // extract prices from product collection
        });
        foreach ($newPrices as $newprice) { //for each price create new  product collection
              $hlp=$products;
             $hlp->unsetRelation("price");
             $hlp->setRelation("price",$newprice);
             $newProducts->push($hlp);
        }
```

**but all  $newProducts has last price item exist in price array**

Comment: clone solved my problem.      $hlp=clone($products);

Answer (score 0):

As the asker says in the comments, the following code solved it:

```
$hlp = clone($products);
```